# Processing complex XML in Hadoop to extract data

Tags: xml, xpath, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I want to process a formatted XML in Hadoop, which is pretty complex and huge and also contain loops.

I tried following options:

1. Loaded XMLs into Hive as a single column and use XPATH queries.
2. Create Hive table using a SerDe.
3. Load XMLs using PIG using XMLLoader.

Option 1 is possible, but becomes difficult in case of getting data very deep within XML.

For Option 2 and 3 Hive SerDe and Pig Loader requires Schema to be defined explicitly, so can not be done.

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pig and Pig UDF for extracting data from XML files.For extracting data you can use regular expression or Xpath.You can use piggybank for multiple operations.